# FreeMarker and HTML

Tags: java, freemarker

I'm trying to use a **FreeMarker** template,
Here's my code:

```
@GET
    @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    @Path("{queue}")
    public String test(@PathParam("queue") String qy,
    @Context HttpServletRequest request) {

        Map<String,Object> model = new HashMap<String,Object>();

         String listTemplate = "<HTML><HEAD><STYLE>${css}</STYLE></HEAD><BODY><UL> the queue includes : ${queues}</UL></BODY></HTML>";

String listCss = inMemService.getWebCss("list");
        model.put("css", listCss);

         String result = null ; 
        IQueue queue = com.myproject.hc.Main.getHzInstance().getQueue(qy);

        // Build the data-model

                    Object[] array = queue.toArray();
                int size = queue.size();
                int i; 
               for (i = 0; i < size ; i ++) {

                   temp = temp + " " + array [i] + " ";
               }


            model.put("queues", temp);

             Template template ;
            try {
                template = new Template("process", new StringReader(
                        listTemplate), new Configuration());
                Writer stringWriter = new StringWriter();
                template.process(model, stringWriter);
                stringWriter.flush();
                result = stringWriter.toString();
            } catch (IOException e) {

            } catch (TemplateException e) {

            } 

            return result;
    }
```

However, when I add to the queue, and go the `@Path`, I get the following output, which doesn't recognize as `HTML`:

```
<HTML><HEAD><STYLE>body {background-color: lightgrey;} h1 {color: black;text-align: left;} p {font-family: verdana;font-size: 20px;}</STYLE></HEAD><BODY><UL> the queue includes :  LA  NYC </UL></BODY></HTML>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your HTML is fine, you need to declare in code you are returning HTML (and not JSON).

You should replace [@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19226-01/820-7627/gipxf/index.html) with:

```
@Produces({MediaType.TEXT_HTML})
```

> The @Produces annotation is used to specify the MIME media types or representations a resource can produce and send back to the client.